# possible issues with class dependencies in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dependency-management

After learning power of Rails framework, I have started learning ruby. In Ruby, I learnt that I can add methods to a class at runtime. In Java, we have to define all methods before compilation. I suppose, this advantage in Ruby gives rise to issues with class dependancies. As I am new to Ruby, could anyone please explain in what way do I lose control by adding methods dynamically.

Comment: I do not know, I am guessing there must be some disadvantage of it. Right now I can think of dependency management.

Comment: You lose the ability for a compiler to perform static type checking and method availability without actually running your code.

Comment: You also run the risk that someone may open a class you relied on the behavior of and change the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to add methods at runtime doesn't impact the dependencies in any way, or at least not any more than writing any other code would.

The only difference is that you can now have methods "written" as-needed, but you will still have the same dependency issues if you wrote the code yourself. Since ruby is a dynamic language, it's sense of dependencies is rather different from a more "traditional" statically compiled language like C++ or Java, but even in Java you can load arbitrary code at runtime (it's much more difficult, but still possible).